# Prove that this ring contains infinitely many minimal prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

I get stucked on this problem, hope some one can help me solve this.

> Prove that the ring $\mathbb Z[x_{1}, x_{2}, ...]/(x_{1}x_{2}, x_{3}x_{4},x_{5}x_{6}, ...)$ contains infinitely many minimal prime ideals.

I even can't get the structure and the characteristic of the ring $\mathbb Z[x_{1}, x_{2}, ...]/(x_{1}x_{2}, x_{3}x_{4}, ...)$. 
Thanks.

Comment: How many minimal primes are there in $k[x,y]/(xy)$?

Comment: https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/11/26/exhibit-a-ring-with-infinitely-many-minimal-prime-ideals/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write such primes by picking up one variable at a time from the products $x_1x_2$, $x_3x_4$, $x_5x_6$, and so on. (Every prime ideal containing $(x_1x_2,x_3x_4,x_5x_6,\dots)$ must contain one variable from each product.) For example, one of such minimal primes is $P=(x_1,x_4,x_5,\dots)$. It is clear (I hope) that in this way you will find infinitely many minimal primes.

Comment: Got it. thanks so much