# Prove that the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,...]/(x_1x_2,x_3x_4,x_5x_6,...)$ contains infinitely many minimal prime ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

[Prove that ring contains infinitely many minimal prime ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501100/prove-that-ring-contains-infinitely-many-minimal-prime-ideals)

I've seen this answer but I don't get it why the ideals mentioned in this answer is prime and minimal.
Would you please explain?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be that ring. For example, let $\mathfrak{p} = \langle x_1,x_3,x_5,\dotsc \rangle$. Then $R/\mathfrak{p} = \mathbb{Z}[x_2,x_4,x_6,\dotsc]$ is an integral domain. Hence, $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal. The prime ideals contained in $\mathfrak{p}$ correspond 1:1 to the prime ideals in the localization $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$. Now in that ring we have $x_n x_{n+1}=0$ for all odd $n$ and $x_{n+1}$ is invertible, so that $x_n=0$. In particular, the image of $\mathfrak{p}$ is just $0$. This means that $R_{\mathfrak{p}} = \mathbb{Z}[x_2,x_4,x_6,\dotsc]_{(0)} = \mathbb{Q}(x_2,x_4,x_6,\dotsc)$ is a field. Fields have exactly one prime ideal.

Comment: Good to see you in these parts of the interwebs again!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen :-)